# Loop vectorising of vector3d products using Eigen

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen

Hi I'm using Eigen to roll or vectorise a number of loop operations in a particle filter.

In essence I have two matricies

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<N, 3> A;
Eigen::Matrix<3, N> B;
```

Where N is a large number.

And I would like a one line which does the equivalent of:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix<N, 1> D;
for (size_t i=0; i< N; i++)
{
   D.row(i) = A.row(i)*B.col(i);
}
```

I had been trying to use `D =A.rowwise()*B.colwise()` but these broadcasting methods do not define an `operator*()` between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that is pretty much optimal for small vectors like these.

```
Eigen::MatrixX3d A;
Eigen::Matrix3Xd B;
Eigen::VectorXd D = (A.array() * B.array().transpose()).rowwise().sum();
```

Fine-tuning this expression for larger vector size, e.g. if these were square matrices, is a bit of a challenge but for 3 rows/columns it works fine.

If you can chose the shape of your matrices, consider changing to this:

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3Xd A, B;
Eigen::VectorXd D = (A.array() * B.array()).colwise().sum();
```

or this:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixX3d A, B;
Eigen::VectorXd D = (A.array() * B.array()).rowwise().sum();
```

Both produce assembly that looks very good and makes full use of vector instructions. Tested with Eigen-3.4.0, GCC-11.3 `-O3 -DNDEBUG`. The second one is better with low dimensions (`MatrixX2d` up to `MatrixX4d`). The first will scale better to large sizes.

Comment: Ah I think I see what you did here, vector multiplicaiton (or dot product) is essentially a element wise multiplication plus a sum along the rows.

Comment: Only thing does the array class have a transpose method? You may have to transpose it before making it an array.

Comment: @rocklegend it does. The code compiled. I looked at the assembly before posting